# navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange not working while using audio jack

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, navigator, mediadevices

I'm trying to respond to the device change events using MediaDevice API as below

```
_trackDeviceChange: function () {
        var e = this
        navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = function () {
          navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (n) {
            e.get('allVideoSourceDevices').clear(),
            e.get('allAudioSourceDevices').clear(),
            e.get('allVideoSourceDevices').pushObjects(t.default.filter(n, [
              'kind',
              'videoinput'
            ])), e.get('allAudioSourceDevices').pushObjects(t.default.filter(n, [
              'kind',
              'audioinput'
            ])), e.get('videoSourceDevice') && !t.default.find(n, {
              deviceId: e.get('videoSourceDevice.deviceId'),
              kind: 'videoinput',
              label: e.get('videoSourceDevice.label')
            }) ? e.set('deviceNotFound', 'camera')  : e.get('audioSourceDevice') && !t.default.find(n, {
              deviceId: e.get('audioSourceDevice.deviceId'),
              kind: 'audioinput',
              label: e.get('audioSourceDevice.label')
            }) && e.set('deviceNotFound', 'microphone')
          })
        }
      }
```

It is working only for USB devices not working for 3.5m jacks

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the `devicechange` event only fires when the set of devices changes.

Technically this is not the case when you connect or disconnect a mini jack and therefore the `devicechange` event does not fire. The device is part of the set of devices no matter if a cable is connected or not.

But when you connect a device by USB the set of devices does change and a new device gets added which was previously not available and consequently the `devicechange` event fires.

Comment: Your thinking is right.
I tested using a lot of devices. Even with Bluetooth devices. It fires for Bluetooth devices also. Then I went through most of the library where this kind of functionality exits. And everywhere it's the same. And then I came to the conclusion that `mediaDevice` treat mini-jack as an inbuild device only. It won't consider as an external device. And the good part is, the stream doesn't break.

Comment: I might be wrong in streaming part bcoz I got the hear about an issue where audio is not available for a recorded video. The root cause is still not debugged. If the issue occurs for muting the audio input setting or any other way rather than device change, then I'm 100% sure for the stream part.